# How to add button more link after div class

Tags: php

I have a content html

```
$output = '<div class="elementor-image-box-wrapper">
    <div class="elementor-image-box-content">
        <h3 class="elementor-image-box-title"><a href="#">Industrial</a></h3>
        <p class="elementor-image-box-description">With OT’S tailored workwear solutions, you can op for a comprehensive program that takes care of your requirements entirely or...</p>
    </div>
</div>';
```

I use preg_replace to add button link inside paragraph class elementor-image-box-description

```
$link = '<a href="#">Read more</a>';
$output = preg_replace( '/^<p class="elementor-image-box-description">(.*)<\/p>$/', '<p class="elementor-image-box-description">$1</p>'.$link, $output );
```

echo $output;

But result not work

Comment: If you don't know what `^` and `$` at the start & end of a regex pattern do, then you should go read up on that first of all now.

Comment: @CBroe thanks you, I have remove ^ and $ is work ok

Comment: "Not work" is a pretty vague description, what does that mean? Also, regular expressions on HTML markup are usually not a good idea

Answer (score -2):

I assume you hold all your html in $output and you want to change some parts.

I suggest another way to do it.

create a php file for your component

**my-component.php:**

```php
<div class="elementor-image-box-wrapper">
    <div class="elementor-image-box-content">
        <h3 class="elementor-image-box-title"><a href="#">Industrial</a></h3>
        <p class="elementor-image-box-description">With OT’S tailored workwear solutions, you can op for a comprehensive program that takes care of your requirements entirely or...</p>
        <?php echo $link; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

then you can

```php
$link = '<a href="#">Read more</a>';
ob_start();
require_once('my-component.php');
$output = ob_get_clean();
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Where do you exchange anything in the given snippet?

Comment: @NicoHaase thought my example is self-explanatory, but if OP ask i would be glad to explain.

Comment: Feel free to add an explanation anyways